# Use of the possessive e.g. "ma chérie"

Tags: possessif

Would one use "my" with darling (ie "ma chérie") to refer to a lover only, or can one also use it to refer to their child, or maybe a friend? How does using "chérie" on its own differ?

Answer (score 7):

*Mon chéri* and *ma chérie* can definitely be used with sons and daughters too.

Between friends or colleagues, "ma chérie" is sometimes used, often but not always with a humorous and/or sarcastic way.

*Chéri* and *Chérie* alone are almost exclusively limited to lovers.

Comment: I must disagree about the humourous/sarcastic way between friends. My wife calls her best friend "ma chérie", in a sentence like "Ca va ma chérie ?". It just makes a proximity, and has to be used between girls... Otherwise it would be awkward, and ambigous about the relationship. As an exemple, Cristina Córdula calls everyone "ma chérie" too :)

Comment: @Random "Ma chérie" can indeed also be used genuinely between friends. Answer updated to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker I can tell you that you can use "my" (as in "Comment vas-tu ma chérie ?) for intimate people lovers, sons and daughters, even best friends (even if it may only be used by women).

BUT, you would only use "chéri" without pronoun for lovers (as in 'Comment vas-tu chérie ?' )